# How can the following equation be written in this form?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

So there is this equation:

$$
y(t) = \frac{A}{1+w^2C^2}[sin(wt) -wCcos(wt)]
$$

I've been told that it can be written in the form of:

$$
y(t)= Esin(wt + \theta)
$$

where

$$
E = \frac{A}{\sqrt{1+w^2C^2}}
$$

and

$$
\theta = -tan^{-1}(wC)
$$

I've been trying to make sense of this for a while now, but I honestly have no idea how you go from a to b.

I was hoping somebody from here could shed some light on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working backwards we get
$$y(t)=E\left(\sin(wt)\cos(\theta)+\cos(wt)\sin(\theta)\right)$$
and $$\theta=-\tan^{-1}(wt)$$
Can you finish?
also we have $$\cos\left(-\tan^{-1}(wt)\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2w^2}}$$
note that $$\sin\left(-\tan^{-1}(wt)\right)=-\frac{tw}{\sqrt{1+w^2t^2}}$$
is it clear now?

Comment: so rearranging the 2nd equation gives   sin(theta) = -wtcos(theta), but I don't see how substituting this into the double angle equation helps. It makes it look messier. From the last equation, I can get as far as cos^2(theta) = 1/(1+t^2w^2), but I can't figure out what to do with that.

Comment: Im really sorry, I just realised I made a mistake when in the equation: theta = -tan^-1(wC). Ive edited it now. Hope it isn't too much of an issue.

Comment: Ya yes, I think I figured it out now, thank you for your help!